# Out Of Stock Product Display On Frontend and Catalog search whether System->Configuration->Inventory->Display Out of stock Set to No

Tags: magento-1.9

Hey Can you tell Me how to display out of stock product too on frontend and catalof search whether it set in cofif Display out of stock is No.Override which class for Solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rewrite setInStockFilterToCollection method in Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Resource_Stock class.

Comment: Yeah, it is just a constraint on the query statement